# Django - i cant migrate my model "prestamo"

Tags: python, django, postgresql, django-models, foreign-keys

this is my model

```
class  Prestamo(models.Model):
    lector = models.ForeignKey( Lector, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    libro = models.ForeignKey(Libro, on_delete=models.CASCADE , related_name='libro_prestamo') 
    fecha_prestamo = models.DateField()
    fecha_devolucion = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
    devuelto = models.BooleanField()
```

and this is my error in console

```
  return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
django.db.utils.IntegrityError: inserción o actualización en la tabla «lector_prestamo» viola la llave foránea «lector_prestamo_libro_id_c94b640a_fk_libro_libro_id»
DETAIL:  La llave (libro_id)=(0) no está presente en la tabla «libro_libro».
```

i dont know how to solve it

Comment: Why should I not upload images of code?
https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try deleting/removing your `db.sqlite3` file and all your migration files in migration folder
then run `python manage.py makemigrations` followed by `python manage.py migrate`